# How to disable HTML escaping of labels in KnpMenuBundle

Tags: symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

I want to render an `HTML` label like:

```
$menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
    'route' => 'dashboard', 
    'label' => '<i class="fa-icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Dashboard</span></a>',
    'extra' => array('safe_label' => true)
    )
);
```

And I've pass the proper option while rendering:

```
{{ knp_menu_render('WshCmsHtmlBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {'allow_safe_labels': true} ) }}
```

But my label is still being escaped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried your question and it's the answer for me and work with me  perfectly with route :) thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok, the answer is!

You set up extra items on menu item not by 'extra' key but by 'extras' key. 
So when you setup the item like this:

```
$menu->addChild('Dashboard', array(
    'route' => 'dashboard', 
    'label' => '<i class="fa-icon-bar-chart"></i><span class="hidden-tablet"> Dashboard</span></a>',
    'extras' => array('safe_label' => true)
)
);
```

it works fine!

Comment: Ahh, we normally use the setExtra method instead of the array initialization.  Good catch on the missing 's' for extras!

Comment: I just did this on a project and it's worth noting that in order for it to work BOTH safe_label options need to be set in the factory and the view. ('extras' => array('safe_label' => true) & {'allow_safe_labels': true}

Answer (score 11):

There's two steps to achieve this.

### 1. MenuBuilder

You have to set `safe_label` to `true` in `extras`. Note that you can now write `HTML` in your label.

```
$menu->addChild('Home<i><b></b></i>', array(
    'route' => 'homepage',
    'extras' => array(
        'safe_label' => true
    ),
));
```

### 2. Twig

You have to filter the output of `knp_menu_render()` so that it prints raw `HTML` (see [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/raw.html)).

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'allow_safe_labels': true}) | raw }}
```

### Warning

Please be aware that this may be dangerous. From the [documentation](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenu/blob/master/doc/01-Basic-Menus.markdown):

> Use it with caution as it can create some XSS holes in your application if the label is coming from the user.

Answer (score 1):

I used FyodorX's method to add a strong tag. It works like a charm but I must say that the raw filter is not necessary