# KnpMenuBundle need to add custom css and html to the link

Tags: html, css, symfony, twig, knpmenubundle

I am using the KnpMenuBundle and I am needing to add custom css and an  tag to one of the links that have with the route of 'uri'=>'#'. How would I accomplish this?

I want the link to look like this:

```
 <a href="#" class="js-sub-menu-toggle">
      <span class="text">Settlements</span><i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i>
 </a>
```

Currently the link is rendering like this:

```
 <a class="asdfasdf" href="#">Settlements</a>
```

Here is my code:

```
 $menu->addChild($name, $array(
           'uri' => '#'
      ));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$menu->addChild('<span class="text">Settlements</span><i class="toggle-icon fa fa-angle-left"></i>', array(
    'uri' => '#',
    'class' => 'js-sub-menu-toggle',
    'extras' => array(
        'safe_label' => true
    ),
));
```

In your **Twig** you have to make `knp_menu_render(`) print raw `HTML` (take a look at [this other answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26132111/3052486)):

```
{{ knp_menu_render('main', {'allow_safe_labels': true}) | raw }}
```

Comment: I however suggest this way of using predefined label property in a array is a Proper way of doing it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16152396/how-to-disable-html-escaping-of-labels-in-knpmenubundle/26132111#26132111